# How to make only one field on the data model to be visible and editable using Kendo UI listview + ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo UI List View that is bound to a datasource. There is a model class that has fields such as {Id, Name, Description, IsActive and so on). I followed the Kendo UI Listview demo and added the Edit and delete icons and the respective controllers. On the edittemplate, I have specified only the Name field but when I click on Edit, I get the textbox or other controls for all the fields on the Model. Is there a way to specify which field to edit ?

Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you need to do, one functionally requested and the other requested from UX point of view.

1. Make sure that in your model you define the field as non editable
2. In your template do not show the field as an editable input.

If you have modify the example from [KendoUI web](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/listview/editing.html) you have the Model in the Schema of the DataSource defined as:

```
schema   : {
    model: {
        id    : "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductID   : { editable: false, nullable: true },
            ProductName : "ProductName",
            UnitPrice   : { type: "number" },
            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" }
        }
    }
}
```

And you want that `ProductName` becomes not editable. Then you have to change it to:

```
schema   : {
    model: {
        id    : "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductID   : { editable: false, nullable: true },
            ProductName : { type: "string", editable: false },
            UnitPrice   : { type: "number" },
            Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
            UnitsInStock: { type: "number" }
        }
    }
}
```

With this you can edit the value but it will not be sent to the server when you update it. But since this is not *nice* you should use change the template to do not allow to change it.

Their current template:

```
<dt>Product Name</dt>
<dd>
    <input type="text" class="k-textbox" 
           data-bind="value:ProductName" name="ProductName"
           required="required" validationMessage="required"/>
    <span data-for="ProductName" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
</dd>
```

Should be changed to be `readonly` and add the class `k-state-disabled`:

```
<dt>Product Name</dt>
<dd>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="k-textbox k-state-disabled" 
           data-bind="value:ProductName" name="ProductName"/>
</dd>
```

or directly change the `input` for something else (for example, a span):

```
<dt>Product Name</dt>
<dd>
    <span data-bind="html:ProductName"></span>
</dd>
```

Running example here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/qh7SD/

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.If we consider the Product model in ur example, I am trying to display and edit the ProductName on the listview. My DB model class has all fields such as UnitPrice and others. But I updated the kendo Model in your example to have just the ProductID and ProductName. I placed all the js code inside document.ready function. When the page loads, the listview doesn't show up but I see error 'Cannot call method 'value' of undefined' on kendo.all.min. Am I missing sthg here?

Comment: Please, edit the original question and include your code or put in JSFiddle and I'll be glad to take a look into it.

Comment: I have updated my question and got it working using a different approach. I was using ASP.NET MVC with Kendo UI.                    I found the following solution and got it working http://kendouiweb.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/listview/how-to-specify-templates-in-listview.aspx#OYlo5urrh02otiu-0uENDw

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about KendoUI, but I would suspect that it would respect Data Annotations. Add similar code to this to your View Model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(YourModelValidation))]
public partial class YourModel
{
}

public class YourModelValidation 
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This will prevent it from auto-scaffolding to screen, where such events occur. Keen to know if it works with Kendo, so please do reply.

Comment: That makes sense. In my case my model is the generated entity from EF. There is a custom class that has IList<Model> class. I guess I need to make a custom Model class to achieve the functionality. I'll try it and will let you know if it works with KendoUI. Thanks.

Comment: Scaffolding the column is not necessary to make the desired column visible and editable on the screen. However, I tried it and it works too. However,in my case on the Kendo listview template and edittemplate, I specified the model  fields that was required to be displayed on the screen.